# How to identify large block of coins referenced in this article, reportedly mined by Nakamoto?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto, traceability

[This article](http://www.theverge.com/2013/5/6/4295028/report-satoshi-nakamoto) refers to a large block of Bitcoins mined in 2009, potentially by Nakamoto.

What's the best way of identifying which block of Bitcoins are referenced in the article?

Comment: The article references something written by Sergio Demian Lerner. I think [this](https://bitslog.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/the-well-deserved-fortune-of-satoshi-nakamoto/) is what it's talking about.